# Finding the change of basis matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

The end of my exercise is as follows:

Let $V$ be a  vectorspace over $\mathbb{R}$ with basis $\alpha=(v_{1}, v_{2},v_{3})$ and $\beta=(u_1,u_2,u_3),$ where
$$u_1=-v_{1}+2v_{2}+v_{3},\quad u_2=-v_{1}-2v_{2}+3v_{3},\quad u_3=4v_{1}+v_{2}+2v_{3}.$$
Find the change of basis matrix $P$ from $\beta$ to $\alpha.$

I don't know how to do. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

The role of the change of basis matrix from $\beta$ to $\alpha$ is to take, as its input, the coordinate vector of any vector $x$ relative to $\beta$ and produce the coordinate vector of (the same vector) $x$ relative to $\alpha$. Symbolically, we could write
$$
P[x]_{\beta} = [x]_{\alpha}.
$$
Each description of a vector $u_i$ in terms of the $v$ vectors gives you one of the columns of $P$. For example, the equation $u_1 = -v_1 + 2v_2 + v_3$ tells you what $P$ should do in the case that $x = u_1$. We have
$$
x = 1u_1 + 0u_2 + 0u_3  \implies [x]_{\beta} = \pmatrix{1\\0\\0},\\
x = (-1)v_1 + 2v_2 + 1v_3 \implies [x]_{\alpha} = \pmatrix{-1\\2\\1}.
$$
It follows that
$$
P \pmatrix{1\\0\\0} = \pmatrix{-1\\2\\1}.
$$
Note that $P(1,0,0)^T$ is the first column of the matrix $P$. Thus, we can conclude that the matrix $P$ has the form
$$
P = \pmatrix{
-1 &?&?\\
2&?&?\\
1&?&?}.
$$
The rest of the matrix can be computed similarly.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now